# Rotating array with one fixed value

Tags: c#, arrays, rotation

I'm building a strong logic and randomized keygen with at base the 'partial key verification'. I need to add it another random function by rotanting an array but all sample i found here at Stack Overflow have different needs as mine.

I'm starting with an array:

```
   int[] q = new int[5];
   for (int i = 0; i < q.Length; i++)
   {
       q[i] = i;
   }
```

Now i have:

```
q[0] = 0;
q[1] = 1;
q[2] = 2;
q[3] = 3;
q[4] = 4;
```

I need to clockwise it but I need to maintain a value immutable, as for example q[2] = 2;

Then first step should result (by adding + 1 clockwise):

```
q[0] = 1;
q[1] = 3; //bypassed 2nd value
q[2] = 2;
q[3] = 4;
q[4] = 0; //come back to 0
```

A second step should be (by adding again + 1 clockwise):

```
q[0] = 3; //bypassed 2nd value
q[1] = 4; 
q[2] = 2;
q[3] = 0; //come back to 0
q[4] = 1;
```

If possible i need also the rollback function... thanks a lot

Thanks both for the help: Meanwhile i created my solution:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < q.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == fixed_int) { } //donothing
            else if ((q[i] + 1) == fixed_int) { q[i] = q[i] + 2; }
            else if ((q[i] + 1) == (q.Length + 1)) { q[i] = 0; }
            else { q[i] = q[i] + 1; }
        }
```

this will fail when the Fix value has not 2 more int forward but it's not my case. Please don't use this code, as it's not working in certain situations. Use the accepted answer because it rocks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the array has at least 2 elements, you may try something like this (set `step` to `+1` and `-1` for different rotations):

```
void Rotate(int[] a, int fix, int step)
{
    int i = (fix + step + a.Length) % a.Length;
    int n = (fix - step + a.Length) % a.Length;
    int t = a[i];
    while(i != n)
    {
        int j = (i + step + a.Length) % a.Length;
        a[i] = a[j];
        i = j;
    }
    a[n] = t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function you can use to achieve your result:

```
public static T[] Rotate<T>(T[] array, int fix)
{
    // check for errors
    if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    if (fix < 0 || fix > array.Length - 1) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

    T[] result = new T[array.Length];

    // copy the input into the results
    Array.Copy(array, 1, result, 0, array.Length - 1);
    result[array.Length - 1] = array[0];

    // restore the location of the fixed item
    int j = ((fix - 1) + array.Length) % array.Length; // index of "fix - 1"
    result[j] = result[fix];
    result[fix] = array[fix];

    return result;
}
```

And here is the accompanying rollback function:

```
public static T[] Rollback<T>(T[] array, int fix)
{
    // check for errors
    if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    if (fix < 0 || fix > array.Length - 1) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

    T[] result = new T[array.Length];

    // copy the input into the results
    Array.Copy(array, 0, result, 1, array.Length - 1);
    result[0] = array[array.Length - 1];

    // restore the location of the fixed item
    int skp = ((fix + 1) + array.Length) % array.Length;
    result[skp] = result[fix];
    result[fix] = array[fix];

    return result;
}
```

It can be used as follows:

```
var input = new[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
var result = Rotate(input, 2);      // yields {1, 3, 2, 4, 0}
var rollback = Rollback(result, 2); // yields {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Remember also that this function is generic so it can work with arrays of any type (demonstrated with `char` array below).

```
var charArr = "abcdef".ToCharArray();
var charRslt = Rotate(charArr, 3);    // {'b', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'f', 'a'}
var charRlbk = Rollback(charRslt, 3); // {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}
```